# Exception installing Magento2 sample data: SQL Integrity constraint violation

Tags: magento2, database, magento2-dev-beta, sample-data

I am getting the following error while installing Magento2 with sample data. At the last stage i am getting the below error.[image: Installation error on console]

Magento only installing this sample data which i have installed through composer there is nothing which i can do on that to modify data. Please suggest some way to finish the installation successfully.

Comment: I would suggest asking this sort of question on Magento 2 GitHub as its more like a bug. You have to get the right versions of things together, and until we reach GA the version dependencies are a little more flaky. But it certainly can be made to work. (If you agree, can we close this question please.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a pre stable version of Magento 2: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/907/magento-2-questions-tagged-beta-alpha-pre-alpha-etc-quo-vadis

Answer (score 0):

What Magento build? How did you modify composer.json? Suggest you use:

composer require magento/sample-data:~0.74.0-beta15

There were issues with earlier sample data packages.

If you're using an older build of either Magento or sample data, you should probably uninstall and start over.

Comment: I have used "composer require magento/sample-data:~0.74.0-beta16". And successfully installed all the sample data through composer. But, no luck.